# Открыть галерею fancybox именно с теми изображениями которые в контейнере

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, fancybox

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос, как сделать так, чтоб открылись изображения при клике на кнопку именно те которые находятся в этом же контейнере, у меня на странице находятся идентичные кнопки с контейнерами, но в контейнерах хранятся другие изображения, в моём случае в галерее открываются все изображения которые есть на странице, как бы собирает со всех контейнеров в одно.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.show_plan').on('mouseup', function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox().trigger('click');
    });
});
```

PHP

```
  if (function_exists('estate_floor_plan')):
     echo '<div class="show_plan media-el"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>Floor plan';
     $get_img_src = get_post_meta($properties[$i]['ID'], 'plan_image', true);
         echo '<div class="modal-compare compare-plan">';
           foreach ($get_img_src as $img):
              echo'<span class="c">
                 <a class="fancybox" href="'.$img.'" rel="group"></a>
              </span>';
            endforeach;
          echo '</div>';
       echo '</div>';
 endif;
```

Я то проблему понял, что скорее всего у меня подхватывает все изображения из-за того что класс везде одинаковый, но я не знаю как правильно написать JS, чтоб он правильно выбирал в модальное окно галереи только те фотографии которые находятся в обёртке .show-plan на которую кликнули

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атрибут rel у каждого контейнера должен быть уникальный. Тогда каждая группа будет обособлена